# Regarding throwing an exception after catching it

Tags: java, exception

I have made a class which is custom exception class and it contains many overloaded methods

```
public class abcException extends Exception
{}
```

I have another class in which I import the above abcException class also

```
import com.system.error.abcException;
class fgh
{

void dhj() throws abcException //method that might throw Exception
{
try

{
}
catch(Exception bse) {
      log.logError(bse.getMessage(), bse);
      throw new abcException(bse.getMessage(), bse);
}
}
```

Now my query is that as shown  in above class , it contains a method named dhj() which
might throw a custom Exception but why inside catch block we again throw the exception after logging
Is it right practice? Please advise.please advise is it ok to have such thing or not

Answer (score 2):

Such practice is acceptable. Consider an example when you create a database driver which would work with SQLite and/or MySQL. Public API of your class has a method `connect()`. Let's consider you want to handle a situation when a connection can't be established because the connection parameters are wrong. Here you have fundamental difference between the way how SQLite and MySQL work. SQLite is a file-based and you will probably catch e.g. `FileNotFoundException`, whereas MySQL is accessed by network and you can get `ConnectException`. The public API user doesn't want to know what happened in the deeps of your driver, so you just wrap those exceptions with let's say `MyDbDriverConnectException` which is more convenient to handle.

UPD: As for exceptions logging, logging and rethrowing is bad practice because you create situation when one exception is logged multiple times. Read [this great post](http://codemonkeyism.com/7-good-rules-to-log-exceptions/) for more information.

Comment: To add to this, when you are wrapping the exception in a common custom exception, the client now only needs to handle that common exception instead of numerous specific exceptions thrown in the called method. Thus it reduces the number of exceptions to be handled at the client end.

Comment: @Andrey please advise is it ok to have such thing or not

Comment: @user1924563 as for logging before rethrowing - it is not ok, because you can create a situation when you'll have one exception logged multiple times. But _rethrowing_ is ok in general.

Comment: @Andrey then what need to do for logging since I want to log the exception also..!

Comment: @user1924563, when you call `dhj()` you need to handle exception where you can log it. Read this excellent post for exception logging practices: http://codemonkeyism.com/7-good-rules-to-log-exceptions/

Comment: Your link to codemonkeyism is broken

Answer (score 1):

If you are using throws clause, you need not catch it again in the same method, the client which uses that method should explicitly handle that exception or again put it in throws clause, at-some point of time someone should handle that exception else code won't compile. In this case I think catch and throw are redundant

Answer (score 0):

In case of exceptions

1. catch it and log it.
   or
2. throw it

never log and re-throw the same exception.

For eg: in Java servlets, servlet method is allowed to throw only ServletException or IOException

So if in your logic some other exception occurs you wrap that exception in a ServletException and rethrow it.But caching the `Exception` is bad and shows that you dont have much idea on what you are doing within the method. That will even catch RuntimeExceptions which are not supposed to be caught in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

log and throw is often considered to be an anti-pattern, see http://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns#logAndThrow

`catch (Exception e)` is usually bad, because this way you catch RuntimeExceptions which are not supposed to be caught. Usually we catch checked exceptions only. Note that Java 7 has multicatch feature `catch(FirstException | SecondException e)`

as for catch and rethrow it's OK, it is exception translaction, see http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=120

Comment: please advise is it ok to have such thing or not